# Editing article returns "Authored by" to default value

Tags: 7, nodes

I changed the default author of a node to blank (' ') for the needs of my project. So, currently when I create a node, "Authored by" field is empty. Then, I could assign author and this works fine - the assigned author is displayed within the Authoring information.

But when I edit the article, the 'Authored by' field is again blank, so if I just want to change something in the body, I would need to assign author again.

Any suggestions how to make the field to remember its value?

Comment: sounds like a bug, Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Drupal 7, sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the node author to blank? I suspect you applied this to the form in general, not just for new nodes. Thus the content is set to blank whenever you open the form.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I switched to '#default_value' => '' " in       the $form['author']['name'] array. Do you have idea how to make that for the new node, instead of the form itself?

Comment: Are you write custom code for this?